# Let $B$ be a finite subset of $A$ Show $B$ is in some cyclic subgroup of $A$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

Suppose $B$ is a finite subset of $A$. $A =$ {$e^{2πij/n},0 ≤ j < n , n ≥ 1$}.
Show $B$ is contained in some cyclic subgroup of $A$.
I need to give a good generator of this cyclic subgroup of $A$ and show that every element of $B$ is a power of the generator.

I need to find a generator of $A$ and show it works for any subset $B$.

- For $a ∈ A$, $<a>$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$. If $A$ contains some element $a$ where $A = <a>$, then $A$ is a cyclic group. Here, $a$ is a generator of $A$.

I'm not really sure what cyclic subgroup I need. I was thinking about $H =$ {$e^{i\pi\ q}, q∈Z$} maybe?

So $<e^{i\pi\ q}>$ would generate the cyclic subgroup of $A$? And all elements of $B$ would be powers of the generator? I need to define $q$ by giving some formula for it or some conditions to show it works for any $B$. I was thinking something related to $gcd$ maybe? I'm not really sure if it's the right generator though.

Comment: Use `$\langle x\rangle$` for $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Am I mistaken thinking we can use complex roots of unity?

Comment: @Jdella you can, but I didn't use them because I didn't think I had to

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $H=\{-1,+1\}$, so it does not work for arbitrary $B$.

Also $A$ is an infinite group each of whose elements has finite order, therefore it is impossible for $A$ to be a cyclic group, and it therefore makes no sense to talk about a single generator of $A$.

Your intuition about gcd is aiming approximately in the right direction.

But to get anywhere you have to turn that intuition into mathematics.

And the very first step of doing that is to write out explicit expressions for the elements of the finite set $B$, so that you have some actual mathematical expressions to do some arithmetic with.

**Step 1:** Write the elements of the finite set $B$ in the explicit form
$$B = \bigl\{\underbrace{\exp\left(2 \pi i \frac{j_1}{n_1}\right)}_{b_1}, \underbrace{\exp\left(2 \pi i \frac{j_2}{n_2}\right)}_{b_2}, ... \underbrace{\exp\left(2 \pi i \frac{j_M}{n_M}\right)}_{b_M} \bigr\}
$$
for some integers $n_1,...,n_M \ge 0$ and some integers $j_1,...,j_M$ such that $0 \le j_m \le n_m$ for all $m=1,...,M$.
$$

**Step 2:** Find one element of $A$, which we shall express in the explicit form $a = \exp\left(2 \pi i \frac{j}{n} \right)$, such that the cyclic subgroup of $A$ generated by $a$ contains each of $b_1,...,b_M$.

And at this point, I'll give you a hint and stop: You can find a value of $a$ having the even more restrictive form $a = \exp\left(2 \pi i \frac{1}{n} \right)$, in fact all you have to do is to find a single fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ such that each of the fractions $\frac{j_1}{n_1},\ldots,\frac{j_M}{n_M}$ is an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: so the generator is  $a=e^{2πi/n}$, and this generates the cyclic subgroup of $A$, which contains all the elements of $B$. And I need to find the fraction $1/n$ so that all the $j/n$ fractions are integer multiples of $1/n$. 

But since we didn't directly define all the $j/n$ from the elements of $B$, how do we know what $1/n$ fraction we need? For all the $j/n$ to be integer multiples of $1/n$, would the $j/n$ just be fractions where $gcd(j,n)=n$?

Comment: how do I find the fraction $1/n$? I thought it was just some $1/n$ such that the fractions $j/n$ are all its integer multiples?

Comment: If someone gives you a bunch of fractions, do you know how to find a common denominator for them?

Comment: yes, you would just find some common divisor for them or use their $lcm$. So am I looking for some $n$ where $n$ divides $j$? So $n|j $?

Comment: Is it just some $n$ such that $lcm(n_1,n_2,...,n_M)=n$? (Sorry for the many questions, I feel like I get it and that I'm close, but still missing something.)

Comment: Sounds about right.